# SQL: ORDER BY `date` AND START WHERE`value`="something"?

Tags: mysql, sql

**SQL Table:**

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID  |   COLOR   |         DATE        |
|-----|-----------|---------------------|
|  1  | ORANGE    | 2011-11-03 01:14:00 |
|  2  | YELLOW    | 2011-11-03 01:13:00 |
|  3  | GREEN     | 2011-11-03 01:16:00 |
|  4  | BLUE      | 2011-11-03 01:16:00 |
|  5  | PINK      | 2011-11-03 01:12:00 |
-----------------------------------------
```

**The following query gives me the results ordered by date:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 4

-----------------------------------------
| RESULT:                               |
|---------------------------------------|
|  3  | GREEN     | 2011-11-03 01:16:00 |
|  4  | BLUE      | 2011-11-03 01:16:00 |
|  1  | ORANGE    | 2011-11-03 01:14:00 |
|  2  | YELLOW    | 2011-11-03 01:13:00 |
-----------------------------------------
```

**But what if I wanted to order it by date and also start from a specific 'color'?**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 4
START WHERE `color`='blue'

-----------------------------------------
| RESULT I WANT:                        |
|---------------------------------------|
|  4  | BLUE      | 2011-11-03 01:16:00 |
|  1  | ORANGE    | 2011-11-03 01:14:00 |
|  2  | YELLOW    | 2011-11-03 01:13:00 |
|  5  | PINK      | 2011-11-03 01:12:00 |
-----------------------------------------
```

**^What is the correct syntax to get this result?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  y.*
FROM
  YourTable y
WHERE
  y.date <= (SELECT yb.date FROM YourTable yb WHERE yb.color = 'BLUE')
ORDER BY
  y.date DESC
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Updated:

```
SELECT 
  y.*
FROM
  YourTable y
WHERE
  /* The colors 'before' blue */
  y.date < (SELECT yb.date FROM YourTable yb WHERE yb.color = 'BLUE') or
  /* And blue itself */
  y.color = 'BLUE'
ORDER BY
  y.date DESC
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Second update to meet newly discovered criteria.

```
SELECT 
  y.*
FROM
  YourTable y,
  (SELECT yb.id, yb.date FROM yb WHERE color = 'GREEN') ys
WHERE
  /* The colors 'before' green */
  y.date < ys.date or
  /* The colors on the same date as green, but with greater 
     or equal id to green. This includes green itself.
     Note the parentheses here. */
  (y.date = ys.date and y.id >= ys.id)
ORDER BY
  y.date DESC
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: The only problem is, if two rows have the same date/time, it will not start from the row where color='BLUE', it will start from the row with the lower id. Is there any way to make sure it starts from a specific row?

Comment: I updated the time's in the example so you can see what Im saying.

Comment: A slightly modified version. `<=` is changed to `<` to get only the colors with a date before that of BLUE. A second condition included BLUE itself, regardless of date.

Comment: One problem. If I wanted to specify GREEN as my starting color (rather than blue), then blue would not appear in the results, even though blue comes after green on the list.

Comment: So you mean, now the ID's are important too? That's why it's a good idea to specify exactly what rules you need. Examples won't get you there directly, because they don't cover all exceptions. :)

Comment: Second update posted. Now uses a derived table to get the values of green. Advantage is that you only need to specify 'GREEN' once in the query. The values from this sub-select are used in all conditions in the WHERE clause.